# Is it possible to force xcode to save your code?

Tags: xcode, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin that writes something to the .h file with a key command while you're coding in the .m file.

But if I've just made a change in the .h file and go to my .m file and use my plugin directly after, I get an error popup saying that Xcode has changes that is not on the disk yet, and then asks which version I want to use.

If I'm only coding in the .m file and adding the methods and properties to the .h file with my plugin it works fine, it's only when I've just made some changes myself to the .h file and go back to the .m file and use my plugin that I get an error.

So my question is, is it possible to force Xcode to save your code, so you're sure it matches up before you make any changes to what is already on the hard disk?